# Play Framework WS: Returning JSON data as Int

Tags: json, scala, neo4j, playframework-2.1

i was trying out the code from [this](http://www.kotancode.com/2013/05/14/accessing-neo4j-from-play-framework-2-1-with-web-service-futures/) site (with a little modification) and i ran into a problem returning the result as an `Int`.

```
class NeoService(rootUrl: String) {
    def this() = this("http://default/neo/URL/location/db/data")


    val stdHeaders = Seq(
        ("Accept", "application/json"), 
        ("Content-Type", "application/json") 
    )

    def executeCypher(query: String, params: JsObject) : Future[Response] = {
        WS.url(rootUrl + "/cypher").withHeaders(stdHeaders:_*).post(Json.obj(
            "query" -> query,
            "params" -> params
        ))
    }

    def findNode(id: Int) : Future[Option[Int]] = {
        val cypher = """
          START n=node({id})
          RETURN id(n) as id
       """.stripMargin

        val params = Json.obj("id" -> id)

        for (r <- executeCyhper(cypher, params)) yield {
            val data = (r.json \ "data").as[JsArray]
            if (data.value.size == 0)
               None
            else
               Some(data.value(0).as[JsArray].value(0).as[Int])
        }
    }
}
```

if i pass a valid id into `findNode()` it gives me this error:

`[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(validate.error.expected.jsnumber,WrappedArray())))))]`

at the line `Some(data.value(0).as[JsArray].value(0).as[Int])` and if i pass an id that does not exist, it gives me this error:

`[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(validate.error.expected.jsarray,WrappedArray())))))]`

at the line `val data = (response.json \ "data").as[JsArray]`

if i just pass an `Int` like this:

```
... else 
        Some(10)...
```

it works fine. i have no idea what's going on and the what the error message is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What this message is telling you is that the JSON your providing is not parseable in the type you expect.

The first one is about `Some(data.value(0).as[JsArray].value(0).as[Int])`. apparently `data.value(0).as[JsArray].value(0)` is not a Number, and therefore can't be converted to an Int.

For the second one, `val data = (response.json \ "data").as[JsArray]` since the id does not exist, apparently the Json you get has no key 'data', or the value at that key is not an array (null ?).

I suggest you log the value of r.json before parsing. You'll see exactly why it's failing.
You should also avoid using `as` and use validate instead (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaJsonRequests).